# Find the anti-derivative of $8/\sqrt{36-4x^2}$

Tags: integration

Problem is as follows

> Find the anti-derivative of the function $$f(x) = \frac{8}{\sqrt{36-4x^2}}$$

Started Calc 2 last week and we are doing $u$-substitution review. However, no matter what I try, I have no clue how to even begin this problem. $u$-subbing the denominator gets me stuck.

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone! Im definitely going to practice my u-sub more now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

Let $$ x=3\sin(u),\ dx= 3\cos(u)$$

Comment: It might be a good idea to familiarize yourself with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can properly format your mathematics.  Also with respect to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2895217/468350) (which you created then deleted), it is worth noting that there is a [Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) for playing with formatting.

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: Good answer Zach. It may be a good idea to explain how you got that substitution, as to me it isn't completely obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment! But I'm confused from where the 3 comes from. Could you explain the origin/use of it?

Comment: I want to be able to factor the 36 out of the square root. Since there is a 4 already present I want to have 4 times some number squared giving me 36. This number is 3 because 3 squared is 9, times 4 is 36! Now we can factor out 36 and simplify!

Comment: The expression for $dx$ needs a $du$.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, it got me pretty far through the problem. Im currently stuck at 4cosu/sqrt(cos^2u) *du

Answer (score 1):

$$\int  \frac{8}{\sqrt{36-4x^2}}dx$$

put $x=3 \sin t$ thus $dx=3 \cos  t  dt $ and $t=\sin^{-1}(x/3)$
$$\int \frac{8\cdot3 \cos  t  dt }{6\cdot \cos t}=\int 4 dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Factor out $36$ in the radical, and set $u=\dfrac x3$, to obtain a well-known anti-derivative:
$$\int\frac 8{\sqrt{36-4x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac 4{3\sqrt{1-\bigl(\frac x3\bigr)^2}}\,\mathrm dx=4\int\frac {\mathrm d u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=4\arcsin u=\dots$$

Comment: What happened to the 3 in the denominator?

Comment: $\mathrm d u=\dfrac{\mathrm d x}3$.

Comment: Thanks for the help bernard. I actually understand the problem very well now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (with motivational idea): If you know that
$$ \arcsin x = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \; \mathrm d x,$$
then you can rewrite your integrand as
$$\frac{8}{\sqrt{36-4x^2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{9-x^2}} = \frac{2}{ \sqrt{9} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{3} \right)^2}}.$$
Finally, a linear substitution finishes the integral.

Comment: How is this different from my solution?